# htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to short records(tours) according to price (high to low and low to high) in search page, with a form that has submits on change event. Below is the code for the form:

```
{!!Form::open(['route' => 'short','method' => 'GET', 'role' => 'search','class'=>'select-filters'])!!}
    <input type="hidden" name="country" value="{{$country}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="category" value="{{$category}}">
    <input type="hidden" name="days" value="{{$days}}">
    <select name="sort_price" id="sort-price"  onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="" selected="">Sort by price</option>
    <option value="lower">Lowest price</option>
    <option value="higher">Highest price</option>
    </select>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

and I've initialized the values in the same page but give the error `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`:

```
@if(Request::only('country') != null)
    {{$country = Request::only('country')}}
@else
    {{ $country = null }}
@endif
@if(Request::only('category') != null)
    {{$category = Request::only('category')}}
@else
    {{ $category = null }}
@endif
@if(Request::only('days') != null)
    {{$days = Request::only('days')}}
@else
    {{ $days = null }}
@endif
```

The values in `Request::only()` is being passed from the search form in index page. When I die and dump:

```
{{dd(Request::only('country','category','days'))}}
```

I throws the incoming value in array form

[image]
It dumps individual key value pair if i pass only one argument:

```
    {{dd(Request::only('country'))}}
```

or

```
        {{dd(Request::only('category'))}}
```

or

```
        {{dd(Request::only('days'))}}
```

Comment: your name attributes without  double quote!

Comment: sorry let me correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`only()` always returns an array, so to get a string do this:

```
{{ request('country') }}
```

Instead of this:

```
{{ Request::only('country') }}
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexey for your help. I didn't knew this.